# Create Dataframe values using a dictionary lookup and some simple math

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

My original data frame looks like this. These are the first 5 rows:

```
                     Date      Id        Earned        Redeemed    Type
0 2019-01-01 00:01:18.599      69          1000               0  REGULAR
1 2019-01-01 00:04:25.287      69          1000               0  REGULAR
2 2019-01-01 00:18:21.688      70          1000               0  REGULAR
3 2019-01-01 00:29:14.709      71          1000               0      VIP
4 2019-01-01 00:30:26.460      69             0            1000  REGULAR
```

I also have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict = {
        '69': {'REGULAR': 5, 'VIP': 10},
        '70': {'REGULAR': 10},
        '71': {'REGULAR': 1, 'VIP': 2}
       }
```

I would like to create a new dataframe that looks like this:

```
                     Date      Id        Earned        Redeemed    Type   Earned_Normal
0 2019-01-01 00:01:18.599      69          1000               0  REGULAR            200
1 2019-01-01 00:04:25.287      69          1000               0  REGULAR            200
2 2019-01-01 00:18:21.688      70          1000               0  REGULAR            100
3 2019-01-01 00:29:14.709      71          1000               0      VIP            500
4 2019-01-01 00:30:26.460      69             0            1000  REGULAR              0
```

The value in the 'Id' and 'Type' column are used as keys in the dictionary that returns a factor, e.g. id: 69 and type: REGULAR returns 5.

Therefore at index 0, Earned_Normal = Earned/5 = 200.

I have figured out how to do this at a specific row level, how do I do this dynamically for all rows?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including data in a format which is practical for us to use. In any case, this seems like a rather basic operation. Have you tried anything, done any research, read the Pandas docs...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. I recommend you to change your replacement dict keys to int.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

replacement_dict = {
        '69': {'REGULAR': 5, 'VIP': 10},
        '70': {'REGULAR': 10},
        '71': {'REGULAR': 1, 'VIP': 2}
       }

data = [
    {"Id":69,"Earned":1000,"Redeemed":0,"Type":"REGULAR"},
    {"Id":70,"Earned":1000,"Redeemed":0,"Type":"REGULAR"},
    {"Id":71,"Earned":1000,"Redeemed":0,"Type":"VIP"}
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df["Earned_Normal"] = np.nan

print(df)

def transform_row(r):
    # we add a default
    default = {'REGULAR': 5, 'VIP': 10}
    replacement_for_this_row = replacement_dict.get(str(r.Id),default)
    r.Earned_Normal = r.Earned / replacement_for_this_row[r.Type]
    return r


print(df.apply(transform_row, axis=1))
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Dope! Thanks very much! What's the advantage of using integers instead of strings for the keys? Aren't they both immutable?

Comment: It's only to avoid the conversion to get the dict value having the r.Id

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what means that values in dictionary so I will sign this as x.

```py
df['x'] = df['Id'].apply(lambda x: dict[str(x)])
df['Earned_normal'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[2]/x[5][x[4]], axis=1) #here may be problem with index cause I kinda wrong imported csv.
```